# Want to call method after firebase authentication is complete

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
   func signUpPressed(){
    guard let email = signupview.emailTextField.textField.text, let password = signupview.passwordTextField1.textField.text, let name = signupview.nameTextField.textField.text else{
        return
    }
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(User, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print(error)
            return
        }
        let ref  = Database.database().reference()
        let uid = User?.user.uid!
        let userReference = ref.child("Users").child((uid)!)
        let values = ["name": name, "email": email]
        userReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: {(err, ref) in

            if err != nil{
                print(err)
                return
            }
            print("User saved to firebase")
        })
    })
    getUserInfo()     
}
```

What I hope to achieve from this is to be able to store all the User's information after the user has been created in firebase. The problem is that the `getUserInfo` method gets executed before the `print("User saved to firebase")`. I have also learned that firebase is asynchronous, which means that the call always returns immediately, without blocking the code to wait for a result. The results come sometime later, whenever they’re ready. Now what I want to be able to do is to call a method AFTER the results "come in". How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronous doesn't block the main thread and also doesn't prevent the method

```
getUserInfo()
```

from running before response returns , so you need to insert it inside the completion block of `updateChildValues`  like this

```
func signUpPressed(){
    guard let email = signupview.emailTextField.textField.text, let password = signupview.passwordTextField1.textField.text, let name = signupview.nameTextField.textField.text else{
        return
    }
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(User, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print(error)
            return
        }
        let ref  = Database.database().reference()
        let uid = User?.user.uid!
        let userReference = ref.child("Users").child((uid)!)
        let values = ["name": name, "email": email]
        userReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: {(err, ref) in

            if err != nil{
                print(err)
                return
            }

             getUserInfo()   

            print("User saved to firebase")
        })
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the call to `getUserInfo()` inside the completion block that gets executed when the results are ready.